# No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPSessionManager' declares the selector 'POST:parameters:progress:success:failure:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, afhttpsessionmanager

I am new to objective c and IOS, I'm trying to post some values to a url and trying to get the response.

but I can't compile my project because, i'm having this error

> /Users/Desktop/MyIOSApps/Chat System/Chat System/SignInVC.m:92:14: No
>    visible @interface for 'AFHTTPSessionManager' declares the selector 'POST:parameters:progress:success:failure:'

**Imports**

```
#import "SignInVC.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ApplicationEnvironmentURL.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

**Objective-c Code**

```
- (void)submitLoginRequest:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password {

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:email forKey:@"Email"];
    [dict setValue:password forKey:@"Password"];

    NSLog(@"Login dicxtionary : %@", dict);
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.label.text = @"Please wait. Logging in...";

    [hud showAnimated:YES];


    // send user login data to hosting via AFHTTP Async Request in AFNetworking
    [manager POST:BASEURL parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        [hud hideAnimated:YES];
        // Login response validation
        if (responseObject == [NSNull null]) {
            [self showMessage:@"Login Failed" Message:@"Unable to login. Please try again!"];
        }else {
            //NSError *error = nil;
            NSLog(@"response type : %@", NSStringFromClass([responseObject class]));
            //NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            [self checkResultValue:(NSDictionary *)responseObject];
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"AFHTTPSession Failure : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

}
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue. tnx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`POST:parameters:success:failure:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:success:failure:). So simply remove the `progress:nil` from the method call. The whole method call would be look like below.

```
    [manager POST:BASEURL parameters:dict success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        [hud hideAnimated:YES];
        // Login response validation
        if (responseObject == [NSNull null]) {
            [self showMessage:@"Login Failed" Message:@"Unable to login. Please try again!"];
        }else {
            //NSError *error = nil;
            NSLog(@"response type : %@", NSStringFromClass([responseObject class]));
            //NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            [self checkResultValue:(NSDictionary *)responseObject];
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"AFHTTPSession Failure : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

Comment: This work's for me in Stripe iOS implementation, thanks!

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Instance method '-GET:parameters:success:failure:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') fot GET using the v4

Answer (score 9):

In AFNetworking 4.0

**POST:**

```
[manager POST:baseUrl parameters:params headers:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];
```

**GET:**

```
[manager GET:baseUrl parameters:nil headers:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      NSLog(@"getDeviceScanResults: failure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: nstance method '-GET:parameters:success:failure:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') fot GET using the v4